# Как обновить блок?

Tags: php

Допустим есть файл (user_panel). В  случае если есть кука, подгружает панель, но если нет...панель входа, но как после того как пользователь войдет, обновить этот блок...чтоб он сменился на панель... ибо смена происходит после перезагрузки

Comment: Ну все же написано в самом вопросе. Пользователь вошел - появилась кука. Есть кука - при обновлении подгружаем панель. Или что?

Comment: при активации некой функции блок должен перезагрузиться

Comment: Честно говоря, теперь вообще непонятно в чем вопрос. Что такое "блок"? Какое отношение к нему имеют куки? Попробуйте прочитать раздел  [Как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и отредактировать свой вопрос, чтобы стало понятно, в чем проблема.